# Identifying specific differences between two data sets in R

Tags: r

I would like to compare two data sets and identify specific instances of discrepancies between them (i.e., which variables were different).

While I have found out how to identify which records are not identical between the two data sets (using the function detailed here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_data_frames/), I'm not sure how to flag which *variables* are different.

E.g.

Data set A:

```
id      name        dob       vaccinedate  vaccinename  dose
100000  John Doe    1/1/2000  5/20/2012    MMR          4
100001  Jane Doe    7/3/2011  3/14/2013    VARICELLA    1
```

Data set B:

```
id      name        dob       vaccinedate  vaccinename  dose
100000  John Doe    1/1/2000  5/20/2012    MMR          3
100001  Jane Doee   7/3/2011  3/24/2013    VARICELLA    1
100002  John Smith  2/5/2010  7/13/2013    HEPB         3
```

I want to identify which records are different, and which specific variable(s) have discrepancies. For example, the John Doe record has 1 discrepancy in `dose`, and the Jane Doe record has 2 discrepancies: in `name` and `vaccinedate`. Also, data set B has one additional record that was not in data set A, and I would want to identify these instances as well.

In the end, the goal is to find the frequency of the "types" of errors, e.g. how many records have a discrepancy in vaccinedate, vaccinename, dose, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the  [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

Answer (score 9):

This should get you started, but there may be more elegant solutions.

First, establish `df1` and `df2` so others can reproduce quickly:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 100000:100001, name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Jane Doe","John Doe"), class = "factor"), dob = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/1/2000", "7/3/2011"), class = "factor"), vaccinedate = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("3/14/2013", "5/20/2012"), class = "factor"), vaccinename = structure(1:2, .Label = c("MMR", "VARICELLA"), class = "factor"), dose = c(4L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "name", "dob", "vaccinedate", "vaccinename", "dose"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 100000:100002, name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Jane Doee", "John Doe", "John Smith"), class = "factor"), dob = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1/1/2000", "2/5/2010", "7/3/2011"), class = "factor"), vaccinedate = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("3/24/2013", "5/20/2012", "7/13/2013"), class = "factor"), vaccinename = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("HEPB", "MMR", "VARICELLA"), class = "factor"), dose = c(3L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "name", "dob", "vaccinedate", "vaccinename", "dose"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Next, get the discrepancies from `df1` to `df2` via `mapply` and `setdiff`.  That is, what's in set one that's not in set two:

```
discrep <- mapply(setdiff, df1, df2)
discrep
# $id
# integer(0)
# 
# $name
# [1] "Jane Doe"
# 
# $dob
# character(0)
# 
# $vaccinedate
# [1] "3/14/2013"
# 
# $vaccinename
# character(0)
# 
# $dose
# [1] 4
```

To count them up we can use `sapply`:

```
num.discrep <- sapply(discrep, length)
num.discrep
# id        name         dob vaccinedate vaccinename        dose 
# 0           1           0           1           0           1
```

Per your question on obtaining id's in set two that are not in set one, you could reverse the process with `mapply(setdiff, df2, df1)` or if it's simply an exercise of `ids` only you could do `setdiff(df2$id, df1$id)`.

For more on R's functional functions (e.g., mapply, sapply, lapply, etc.) see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

---

Updating with a `purrr` solution:

```
map2(df1, df2, setdiff) %>% 
  map_int(length)
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility.  First, find out which ids both datasets have in common.  The simplest way to do this is:

```
commonID<-intersect(A$id,B$id)
```

Then you can determine which rows are missing from A by:

```
> B[!B$id %in% commonID,]
#       id       name      dob vaccinedate vaccinename dose
# 3 100002 John Smith 2/5/2010   7/13/2013        HEPB    3
```

Next, you can restrict both datasets to the ids they have in common.

```
Acommon<-A[A$id %in% commonID,]
Bcommon<-B[B$id %in% commonID,]
```

If you can't assume that the id's are in the right order, then sort them both:

```
Acommon<-Acommon[order(Acommon$id),]
Bcommon<-Bcommon[order(Bcommon$id),]
```

Now you can see what fields are different like this.

```
diffs<-Acommon != Bcommon
diffs
#      id  name   dob vaccinedate vaccinename  dose
# 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE       FALSE       FALSE  TRUE
# 2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE        TRUE       FALSE FALSE
```

This is a logical matrix, and you can do whatever you want with it.  For example, to find the total number of errors in each column:

```
colSums(diffs)
#         id        name         dob vaccinedate vaccinename        dose 
#          0           1           0           1           0           1
```

To find all ids where the name is different:

```
Acommon$id[diffs[,"name"]]
# [1] 100001
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't specify in my example dataframes above, but my actual data has multiple records for each id. E.g., John Doe could have 5 types of vaccines and each vaccine could have multiple doses. In your first line of code, how could I determine which rows both datasets have in common, not just basing it on id? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There's no concrete answer to that question.  Problem is, if two rows are not identical, then how do you decide whether they are "supposed" to be the same but there's a discrepancy, or whether they are actually different entries entirely.  You have to come up with some criteria to make that decision.

Comment: That's true. One of the datasets is the 'gold standard' (from paper vaccination records) while the other was entered electronically separately, so the first dataset is supposed to be the 'correct' one. Does that help clarify things? The previous person who did this audit looked at discrepancies manually in Excel, finding >1000 errors. Ideally I would want to avoid this manual work! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new package call waldo

```
install.packages("waldo")
library(waldo)

# construct the data frames


df1 <- structure(list(id = 100000:100001, name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Jane Doe","John Doe"), class = "factor"), dob = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/1/2000", "7/3/2011"), class = "factor"), vaccinedate = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("3/14/2013", "5/20/2012"), class = "factor"), vaccinename = structure(1:2, .Label = c("MMR", "VARICELLA"), class = "factor"), dose = c(4L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "name", "dob", "vaccinedate", "vaccinename", "dose"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 100000:100002, name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Jane Doee", "John Doe", "John Smith"), class = "factor"), dob = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1/1/2000", "2/5/2010", "7/3/2011"), class = "factor"), vaccinedate = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("3/24/2013", "5/20/2012", "7/13/2013"), class = "factor"), vaccinename = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("HEPB", "MMR", "VARICELLA"), class = "factor"), dose = c(3L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "name", "dob", "vaccinedate", "vaccinename", "dose"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# compare them
compare(df1,df2)
```

And we get:

```
`old` is length 2
`new` is length 3

`names(old)`: "X" "Y"    
`names(new)`: "X" "Y" "Z"

`attr(old, 'row.names')`: 1 2 3  
`attr(new, 'row.names')`: 1 2 3 4

`old$X`: 1 2 3  
`new$X`: 1 2 3 4

`old$Y`: "a" "b" "c"    
`new$Y`: "A" "b" "c" "d"

`old$Z` is absent
`new$Z` is a character vector ('k', 'l', 'm', 'n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(compareDF)

compare_df(dataframe1, dataframe2, c("columnname"))
```