# How to compare 2 database data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 databases that are almost similar to each other. I want to run a quality check to see if they are 100% matching or not. Can someone share how to compare 2 database data frames in Rstudio?

Comment: What is your expected output? what have you tried? take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429582/identifying-specific-differences-between-two-data-sets-in-r  or here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/vignettes/comparedf.html

Comment: I am expecting the output as True/False or anything that gives me information about matching. I have gone through the resources you provided but those focusing on the 2 datasets or 2 data frames within the same database. I am looking for the resources to compare 2 separate databases' data frames. Thank you!

Comment: `identical(database1, database2)`? Seems like Mael's links have several good options depending on your particulars.